# unbound forward zone syntax

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound

I want to configure unbound to lookup certain domain names with an alternative dns server, with `forward-zone`. The documentation I find have two syntaxes:

```
forward-zone:
name: "mynetwork.com."
forward-addr: 10.0.0.1
```

e.g. [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/unbound) or

```
forward-zone:
name: "mynetwork.com"
forward-addr: 10.0.0.1
```

i.e. name field without dot at the end, e.g. [here](https://calomel.org/unbound_dns.html). Both seems to work for me, but what's the difference between `foo.tld` vs `foo.tld.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific context stated in the question, the `name` in a zone definition (`forward-zone`, `local-zone`, etc) in `unbound.conf`, I don't believe there can be any difference to how these variations are interpreted.
Ie, these two names are interpreted the same.

In some other contexts, a name lacking the trailing dot is considered relative. Here, however we are in a context where there exists no reference point for what the name would be relative to.

It may be a good idea to use the variation with the trailing dot simply for its completely unambiguous meaning to any human readers of the unbound configuration file.
Additionally, It may be nice in terms of consistency if that name is also referenced somewhere else where names can actually be relative and therefore has the trailing dot in that other place.

Answer (score 4):

Difference between `foo.tld` and `foo.tld.` is simple. When you put dot at the end of FQDN your resolver understand that is the absolute name for host or domain. Without dot it's relative name and your resolver could add it's domain to provided FQDN.

For example if you have configured resolver to search in domain `local.home`, request for `foo.tld` would be asked as `foo.tld.local.home` if no `foo.tld` was found.

Comment: thanks! much appreciated. just found a related question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/803033/should-i-append-a-dot-at-the-end-of-my-dns-urls

Comment: But "search" functionality is a stub resolver feature, it doesn't seem applicable to the case in point (unbound config). Relative names make sense in eg zone files where there is an actual origin that you can be relative to, but here there is no such reference point.  I would think the two examples actually mean the exact same thing.